# Prevent Visual Studio 2008 from creating .xsc and .xss files when I try to open an .xsd file

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2008, xsd

I used `xsd.exe` to generate a schema file for some XML. I want to include that schema file in my C# project in Visual Studio, but every time I add the `.xsd` file to my project and then double-click it to open it, Visual Studio creates these `.xss` and `.xsc` files for my `.xsd` file, and it alters my `.xsd` file. How can I get it to stop automagically doing this and altering my schema?

Answer (score 5):

After generating the XSD file, open it in Notepad and update the following:

msdata:IsDataSet="**false**" (was true)

When you now import the file into Visual Studio, it shouldn't create the extra files.

More info [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpide/thread/8ccd1f03-6ef6-4c4f-a14e-b82b28aa31f6).

Comment: This does not work in VS 2017. It still creates those files.

Answer (score 2):

If you're okay with just dealing with the raw XML

Right-Click the XSD, choose Open With.
In the dialog, choose XML editor and Click 'Set as Default.'